# I need help on my Deal or no Deal Java game

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I'm trying to make a simple deal or no deal game. I haven't really progressed yet, but hopefully I can finish it. So far I have only made a JFrame with JButtons and when you click the buttons, the ammount appear. What I'm trying to do next is when you click atleast 3 of the buttons, a dialog box will appear. I don't know if this is possible, but if it is, please help me. I only have a few experience on Gui and eventhandling.

here is my code so far:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Dealornodeal2 implements ActionListener{

private JFrame frame = new JFrame("DEAL OR NO DEAL");
private JButton button1 = new JButton(" 1 ");
private JButton button2 = new JButton(" 2 ");
private JButton button3 = new JButton(" 3 ");
private JButton button4 = new JButton(" 4 ");
private JButton button5 = new JButton(" 5 ");
private JButton button6 = new JButton(" 6 ");
private JButton button7 = new JButton(" 7 ");
private JButton button8 = new JButton(" 8 ");
private JButton button9 = new JButton(" 9 ");
private JButton button10 = new JButton(" 10 ");
private JButton button11 = new JButton(" 11 ");
private JButton button12 = new JButton(" 12 ");
private String amm[]={"25,000","50,000","75,000","100,000"}; 
int number;
private boolean clicked = false;


//constructor for deal or no deal
public Dealornodeal2(){

    frame.setSize(500,400);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(3,3));
    frame.add(button1);
    frame.add(button2);
    frame.add(button3);
    frame.add(button4);
    frame.add(button5);
    frame.add(button6);
    frame.add(button7);
    frame.add(button8);
    frame.add(button9);
    frame.add(button10);
    frame.add(button11);
    frame.add(button12);

    button1.addActionListener(this);
    button2.addActionListener(this);
    button3.addActionListener(this);
    button4.addActionListener(this);
    button5.addActionListener(this);
    button6.addActionListener(this);
    button7.addActionListener(this);
    button8.addActionListener(this);
    button9.addActionListener(this);
    button10.addActionListener(this);
    button11.addActionListener(this);
    button12.addActionListener(this);
```

}

//actionlistener
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent a){

```
    if(a.getSource() == button1){
        button1.setText(amm[(int)(Math.random() * amm.length)]);
        button1.setEnabled(false);


    }
    else if(a.getSource() == button2){
        button2.setText(amm[(int)(Math.random() * amm.length)]);
        button2.setEnabled(false);

    }
    else if(a.getSource() == button3){
        button3.setText(amm[(int)(Math.random() * amm.length)]);
        button3.setEnabled(false);

    }
    else if(a.getSource() == button4){
        button4.setText(amm[(int)(Math.random() * amm.length)]);
        button4.setEnabled(false);

    }
    else if(a.getSource() == button5){
        button5.setText(amm[(int)(Math.random() * amm.length)]);
        button5.setEnabled(false);

    }
    else if(a.getSource() == button6){
        button6.setText(amm[(int)(Math.random() * amm.length)]);
        button6.setEnabled(false);

    }
    else if(a.getSource() == button7){
        button7.setText(amm[(int)(Math.random() * amm.length)]);
        button7.setEnabled(false);

    }
    else if(a.getSource() == button8){
        button8.setText(amm[(int)(Math.random() * amm.length)]);
        button8.setEnabled(false);

    }
    else if(a.getSource() == button9){
        button9.setText(amm[(int)(Math.random() * amm.length)]);
        button9.setEnabled(false);

    }
    else if(a.getSource() == button10){
        button10.setText(amm[(int)(Math.random() * amm.length)]);
        button10.setEnabled(false);

    }
    else if(a.getSource() == button11){
        button11.setText(amm[(int)(Math.random() * amm.length)]);
        button11.setEnabled(false);

    }
    else if(a.getSource() == button12){
        button12.setText(amm[(int)(Math.random() * amm.length)]);
        button12.setEnabled(false);

    }



}
```

}

Comment: Are you looking for a magic event that takes three button clicks to activate? Even if such a thing did exist, I don't know that I would take the time to find it. Just use a counter. **Click** Increment. Are we at three yet? **Click** Increment. Are we there yet? **Click** Increment. BOOM! We are at three! Do something special, and then reset our counter to zero.

Comment: Consider using arrays instead of `button1`, `button2`, `button3`, ... This will be more fun to maintain!

Comment: If you want to keep track of all the clicks, either use a separate counter or use the Java mod ( % ) operator on the counter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to have a counter in your `actionPerformed` method and then display a `Swing` popup.  There's no magic behind it.

In your `Swing` class:

```
private int buttonsPressed = 0;

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    buttonsPressed++;
    if(buttonsPressed >= 3) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You clicked three buttons", "App Title", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        buttonsPressed = 0; //Assuming you want to reset the functionality
    }
}
```

There's obviously more elegance you can add, but that's the general idea.  In your particular use case, I would probably add all of your potential buttons to a `List` so that you can verify the source of the `ActionEvent`.  e.g.,

```
private final List<JButton> buttons = new ArrayList<JButton>();

public DealOrNoDeal {
    // your normal initialization
    buttons.add(button1);
    buttons.add(button2);
    // ... and so on
}
```

... then you can verify the input.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if(buttons.contains(e.getSource()) {
        //do stuff
    }
}
```